# how to not write every field one by one in project

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way not to write all the fields one by one in `$project`stage.

I mean assume I have database structure as;

```
name: "",
surname: "",
age: "",
location: "",
_id: "",

bla bla bla
```

in `project` stage assume I just want to split the `location` field, the rest of the document is same and should be projected.

`db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {"location" : {$split: ["$location" , 0]} }}])`

the field list is long, and I update the query as;

`db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {name: 1, surname:1, age: 1(and so on)"location" : {$split: ["$location" , 0]} }}])`

Is there any short way?

Comment: Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). Something like `{$addFields:{"location" : {$split: ["$location" , 0]}}}` instead of `$project`

Comment: @Veeram thank you very much. you made my day.

Comment: @Veeram I have a question but while projecting I want to remove `_id` field. with $addFields it seems not possible. How can I solve it?

Comment: You are welcome. 
Use `{$project:{_id:0}}` after `$addFields` stage. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields