# How to not list all fields one by one in project when aggregating?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Mongo 3.2.14

I have a mongo collection that looks like this:

```
{
'_id':...
'field1':...
'field2':...
'field3':...
etc...
}
```

I want to aggregate this way:

```
db.collection.aggregate{
                        '$match':{},
                        '$project':{
                                    'field1':1,
                                    'field2':1,
                                    'field3':1,
                                    etc...(all fields)
                                    }
                        }
```

Is there a way to include all fields in the project without listing each field one by one ? (I have around 30 fields, and growing...)

I have found info on this here:

[MongoDB $project: Retain previous pipeline fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497499/mongodb-project-retain-previous-pipeline-fields/24557029#24557029)

[Include all existing fields and add new fields to document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431773/include-all-existing-fields-and-add-new-fields-to-document)

[how to not write every field one by one in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782945/how-to-not-write-every-field-one-by-one-in-project)

However, I'm using mongo 3.2.14 and I don't need to create a new field, so, I think I cannot use $addFields. But, if I could, can someone show me how to use it?

Comment: *"I have 30 fields and growing...*" Okay then great that you actually looked at some answers but your question here actually does not tell us anything other than that statement. What is the problem? `$project` works by **A** Including only the fields you explicitly ask for **B** Or by **Excluding** the fields you explicitly tell it to do. You do not actually explain what it is that you are really doing.All I see here is `$match` and `$project`, and no reasoning at all as to either **why** the fields need to be included or excluded or what the rest of the pipeline needs to be. Explain your case

Comment: "Is there a way to include all fields in the project without listing each field one by one ? (I have around 30 fields, and growing...)" My question starts before "(I have around 30 fields, and growing...)" if that helps...

Answer (score 23):

Basically, if you want all attributes of your documents to be passed to the next pipeline you can skip the $project pipeline. but if you want all the attributes except the "_id" value then you can pass

```
{ $project: { _id: 0 } }
```

which will return every value except the _id.

And if by any chance you have embedded lists or nests that you want to flatten, you can use the $unwind pipeline

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can skip the $project pipeline altogether. I also noticed that if I do { $project: { _id: 0 } }, then I have to explicitly list all the fields that I want one by one. So, I decided to include the '_id' and delete that field after I put it in a dataframe.

Comment: Here if I have more than 20 fields and want to exclude only 2 of them, can I do it the same way?

Comment: Yes, you can just pass the keys you want to exclude with a value of 0
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#std-label-remove-var

Answer (score 3):

you can use $replaceRoot

```
db.collection.aggregate{
    "$match": {},
    "$project": {
        "document": "$$ROOT"
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$document" }
    }
```

this way you can get the exact document returned with all the fields in the document...you don't need to add each field one by one in the $project...try using $replaceRoot at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Isn't this essentially `g(f(x))` ...?